# Update a sorting index column to move items

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-order-by

If I have the following table & data to allow us to use the `sort_index` for sorting:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort_index` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar_id`, `sort_index`) VALUES
 (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),
 (2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5);
```

I want to be able to do the following in the most efficient manner:

1. Move a foo entry to a given position (scoped by the bar_id)

   - Ensure that the `sort_index` is always 1 indexed **and has no gaps**
   - You should be able to move items to the beginning and end of the list and rule #2 should still be applied
   - It should be done entirely in queries and as few as possible (as the sets could be very large and looping over them doing individual `UPDATE`s is not ideal)

To clarify what I'm trying to do, lets assume the table was empty so we have the following data:

```
id | bar_id | sort_index
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 2
3  | 1      | 3
4  | 1      | 4    
5  | 2      | 1
6  | 2      | 2
7  | 2      | 3
8  | 2      | 4
9  | 2      | 5
```

Then if we were to do the following moves

- Foo 1 to sort_index 3
- Foo 7 to sort_index 1
- Foo 5 to sort_index 5

We should get the following data:

```
id | bar_id | sort_index
1  | 1      | 3
2  | 1      | 1
3  | 1      | 2
4  | 1      | 4    
5  | 2      | 5
6  | 2      | 2
7  | 2      | 1
8  | 2      | 3
9  | 2      | 4
```

And `SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY bar_id, sort_index;` gives us:

```
id | bar_id | sort_index
2  | 1      | 1
3  | 1      | 2
1  | 1      | 3
4  | 1      | 4  
7  | 2      | 1
6  | 2      | 2
8  | 2      | 3
9  | 2      | 4
5  | 2      | 5
```

Comment: To clarify your question: given the inserts above, you want to insert another row with `bar_id`=1 at the beginning, resulting in updates (of column `sort_index`) of all subsequent rows where `bar_id` is 1?

Comment: To summarise your requirements, for any sets of "bar_id", the sort_index MUST start from zero and increment by 1 till the largest sort_index number. And you want to do this entirely in MySQL for any move/add/remove operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a single query: something along the lines of `UPDATE foo SET sort_index = sort_index + 1 WHERE bar_id == b AND sort_index < s1 AND sort_index >= s2`, where `b` is the `bar_id` of the row to be moved, `s1` is the current `sort_index` of that row, and `s2` is the the `sort_index` you want to move it to. Then, you'd just change the `sort_index` of the row.

You'd probably want to do the two queries inside a transaction. Also, it might speed things up if you created an index on the `sort_index` using something like `CREATE INDEX foo_index ON foo (sort_index)`.

(By the way, here I'm assuming that you don't want duplicate `sort_index` values within a given `bar_id`, and that the relative order of rows should never be changed except explicitly. If you don't need this, the solution is even simpler.)

Comment: That's pretty snazzy and almost works perfectly. However it doesn't quite work if I want to move an item to the end of the list, as I end up with 2 with the same finishing sort_index and none filling the old sort_index (e.g. if I move an item from 3 to 5 I end up with 2 with sort_index of 5 and nothing with a 3).

Comment: Actually there are some situations (like moving to the end of the list) where you need to use this instead: UPDATE foo SET sort_index = sort_index - 1 WHERE bar_id == b AND sort_index > s1 AND sort_index <= s2

Comment: Ah yes, of course. In fact, it's not just when you're moving it to the end of the list, it's whenever you're moving it forward.