# How to let a user insert anywhere in a list?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of items stored in the database. Each item has an id column, a title, and a position column (int).

By default, whenever the user adds a new item to the list, its id is put in the position. So if you have 3 items, with ids 1, 2, 3, their positions will be 1, 2, 3, as well.

Then when fetching the positions, I will do `ORDER BY position ASC` within my SQL query.

The problem is, the user wants a feature where he can add a new item anywhere within the existing items.

So if you have items 1, 2, 3 with positions 1, 2, 3, he could choose to add a new item at position 2, which will then result in items 1, 2, 3, 4, having the positions: 1 3 4 2

So item # 4 will be put at position 2, item # 2 and 3 will be pushed down to positions 3 and 4, etc.

What's the simplest / most efficient algorith to accomplish this inserting?

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581758/mysql-update-a-sorting-index-column-to-move-items), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113005/updating-an-order-column-mysql) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995770/best-way-to-implement-reorderable-collection-and-persist-it-to-database/1995800#1995800).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method from a code standpoint is to use a linked-list style, where you have a next element id, rather than an order value.  This is less useful in small lists, but when you begin to grow the list size, it makes updates/moves/removals much cleaner and prevents from possibly updating thousands of tuples to make 1 order change.

++ I don't have an exact code example on hand, but you would make a call for all the list's of a user

```
SELECT Posts.id, Posts.next, Posts.content, User.firstPost FROM db.posts AS Posts 
JOIN db.user as User ON Posts.ownerid = User.id 
WHERE User.id='123' AND Posts.active = 1;
```

This would get all the posts of a single user, and then you would have a field that contains the id of the next post.  To start you would need a key to identify the first post (store the id of the first post in the user's info).  After you pull the first post, you grab it's 'next' value, and use that to identify the next post.

This seems a little crazy for a short list, but think about a user with 1000 posts.  If they need to add 1 post in the 2nd position.  In a traditional numeric ordering system, you would now need to update 999 other rows with a +1 update.   With this solution, if you need to insert a post in the second position, you simply query the first post to get it's next value.  Once you have it, you change it to be the value of the new second post, and set the second post's next value to be the one originally held by the first.

```
[1st Post] --Next---> [2nd Post] --Next---> [3rd Post]
```

After Insert:

```
[1st Post] -.                          .--> [2nd Post] --Next---> [3rd Post]
            `--Next--> [New 2nd Post]--`
```

Comment: Keep in mind that using a linked list like this will make it hard to read the ordered list from the database - you can't do `ORDER BY` in sql anymore.  You either have to read one row at a time, or do the ordering in your application (that's what I would do).

Comment: Correct, your application will do the ordering, but you still retrieve all the same data in the same manner (requesting all the tuples for a given user).  Instead of indexing by Count or Order, you index by ID.  This makes searches in the database faster, and when it comes to pagination, you only need to provide the id of the first post on each page.