# Order posts by number manually entered by the user

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a website which its admin user logs into a restricted area and adds content that is displayed on the public area. The admin wants a simple input text field on the post insert/edit form where he can type a number that determines in which position that post will be displayed to the public.

So, if the “Foo” post is given the number 3, it should be listed in the 3rd position, the old post 3 should become 4, 4 should become 5, and so on. If post 5 is repositioned to 1, 1 should automatically become 2, 2 should become 3, etc. If the admin reposition, 3 to 2, 2 should just become 3 without the need to change the other ones. If 10 becomes 9, 9 becomes 10 and no need to change other posts' position either. In short, when the position of one single post is changed (or inserted in the middle of existing posts), the remaining posts should have their position shifted accordingly.

I have considered two possibilities:

- create a crazy algorithm that selects each post needed and updates the `position` column;
- implement a linked list in the table so that each post always knows what is the primary key of the next one.

With the first option, when the admin inserts or updates a post's position, all the work is done at that moment, and when the public site is visited, the SQL just selects all the needed posts in a single query and order them by `position`. I don't really know yet how I would implement it, but I'm sure using a lot of code and possibly bad trade-offs it would be possible.

With the second option, there is much less work done during the insert/update, but when users access the site, I need to do one select for each post so that the right positioning can be achieved using the each post's link to the next “node”. So, if I have 150 posts in a given category, I'll have to run 150 selects (one for each post that is pointed to by the current "node". No pagination will be used in this case, and only the titles will be really listed, one below the other, so, I will really list them all.

I would like suggestions to other approaches, insights or improvements on the two possibilities I have described.

### SOLUTION

I accepted @FractlizeR answer because it uses some other established piece of software to support his choice.

I [wrote a small prototype on the solution I ended up using at work](https://github.com/FernandoBasso/crud-custom-position). Of course the code I used at work is different because I was changing a legacy system. Still, I used exactly the same SQL approach as the ones in the prototype. I hope I can improve that prototype and specially its comments soon, but at least it is there in case I or someone else needs to do something similar.

Comment: How about using a float to indicate the post's position? That way you can move a post between two others and still get to have a simple select statement. For example if a post is moved to the third position (between 2 and 3), you just give it the position of 2.5.

Comment: @Faris That will turn into complex logic to try not to run out of float's precision when constantly reordering the same item ;)

Comment: Just to update everybody on the situation, I had to switch to a different task at work, and will be coming back to this problem in a matter of two or three days. I'll consider everybody's suggestions then. Thanks everybody who helped so far. And by the way, [here's a post that made me consider a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206233/how-to-let-a-user-insert-anywhere-in-a-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would vote for #1. This is what, for example, XenForo forum engine does. It uses post `position` for paging and other things. When it needs to insert a new post into a thread, it queries thread for all posts, that needs to be reordered, then for each post calculates a new position and then updates table for all posts, which position changed.

We use XenForo for a long time in production and actually there should be no problems involved since this operation (reorder) is not so complex.

Comment: You mean insert a post in the beginning or in the middle? Also, what about changing a post's position?

Comment: @Fernando I mean any insertion. Appending a new post into the end of the thread doesn't involve recalculation. You just need to get post_count and +1 it to get a position of a new post.